# Get Number from string using SUBSTRING() SQL Server 2008-R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, substring

I have some data that looks like the following:

```
AS WRITTEN                                             | UNITS | ROUTINE
TRANSFUSE - RED BLOOD CELLS 1 UNITS ROUTINE, TRANSF... | 1     | 
TRANSFUSE - RED BLOOD CELLS 2UNITS ROUTINE, TRAN...    | 2     |
TRANSFUSE FRESH FROZEN PLASMA 2 ROUTINE                |       | 2
TRANSFUSE - RED BLOOD CELLS 2 UNITS ROUTINE, TRAN...   | 2     |
TRANSFUSE CRYOPRECIPITATE 10 ROUTINE                   |       |    <- 10 SHOULD BE HERE
```

I am using the following `SELECT` statement to obtain the values, which might be a crude way of doing, but this is my first foray into `SUBSTRING()` `CHARINDEX` ETC.

SELECT statement:

```
, CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING(SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN, CHARINDEX('UNIT', SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN)-2,1) NOT IN (
        '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'
    )
        THEN ''
    ELSE SUBSTRING(SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN, CHARINDEX('UNIT', SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN)-2,1)
  END AS [UNITS]
, CASE 
    WHEN SUBSTRING(SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN, CHARINDEX('ROUTINE', SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN)-2,1) NOT IN (
        '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11'
    )
        THEN ''
    ELSE SUBSTRING(SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN, CHARINDEX('ROUTINE', SO.DESC_AS_WRITTEN)-2,2)
  END AS [ROUTINE]
```

As stated above 10 should be showing in the last column under `ROUTINE` but is not and I do not understand why. All of the others are seem to be working just fine.

Thank you,

**UPDATE**
From the large help from @EkriirkE and @GoatCO I have used the following code as the solution:

```
,(CAST
    (ISNULL
        (REPLACE
            (REPLACE
                (REPLACE
                    (CASE 
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNIT%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNIT%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2) 
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNIT%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNIT%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]STAT%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]STAT%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] STAT%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9] STAT%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]TODAY%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9]TODAY%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2)
                        WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] TODAY%',so.desc_as_written) > 0 
                            THEN SUBSTRING(so.desc_as_written,
                                 PATINDEX('%[0-9] TODAY%',so.desc_as_written)-1,2) 
                    END,
                'S',''),
            'T',''),
        'U','')
    , 0)
AS INT)
) AS [TEST]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be preferable:

```
SELECT *,CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNITS%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNITS%',written)-1,2) 
              WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNITS%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNITS%',written)-1,2) 
         END
        ,CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',written)-1,2)
              WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',written)-1,2)
         END 
FROM  #Table1
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ccbe/2/0)

It might be easiest to wrap the `CASE` statement inside of a replace than to deal with grabbing the proper number of characters given variations, ie:

```
SELECT *,REPLACE(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNITS%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9]UNITS%',written)-1,2) 
                      WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNITS%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9] UNITS%',written)-1,2) 
                 END,'S','')                       
        ,REPLACE(CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9]ROUTINE%',written)-1,2)
                      WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',written) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(written,PATINDEX('%[0-9] ROUTINE%',written)-1,2)
                 END,'S','') 
FROM  #Table1
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I have to play around with it as I am getting the following error `conversion failed when converting the varchar value 's1' to data type int.`

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator it could be that you have a situation where there's no space like `CELLS1` wrapping these in a `REPLACE()` statement might be easiest way to fix that.

Comment: I'll have to do some reading on `REPLACE()` as your answer is my first encounter with it. Thank you for the help

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator Added replace to answer, and they can be nested if you have multiple characters to replace, ie:  `REPLACE(REPLACE(CASE ... END, 'S',''),'U','')` would replace any `S` or `U` that's returned in the `CASE` statement with nothing `''`.

Comment: I have chosen to make this answer as the accepted, both of you helped me out a lot, I just find this to be a more robust answer while it also introduces me to some new functions.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking only 1 char after backing up 2 chars from finding UNIT or ROUTINE.  "10 ROUTINE" returns "0" which is not in your IN list.  i.e. Your code only works for single-digit numbers.  You ought to take -3 chars then 2 chars length and trim the spaces, but then you run into more difficulty if you indeed have running-ins like "2UNITS" vs " 2 UNITS" in your sample

Comment: Thank you much, this did work out well, I am not to worried about the ruuing-ins as they have yet to happen but it is a good point and something for me to consider.

Comment: @MCP_infiltrator you have such a run-in in your example `2UNITS`

Comment: @Goat CO That's why I brought it up... Welcome!